# Hide Element but Don't Remove from Layout

Tags: html, css

I have some icons that I want to show for some elements but hide for others.

But for those elements where the icon is hidden, I'd like the spacing to remain the same.

Is there a way to hide an element's image but maintain the space taken by that element and icon?

Comment: what have you tried? you could familiarize yourself with `visibility` and see if that works ;) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CSS `visibility:hidden` does exactly that, e.g.

```
.hidden-icon {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

You could use `opacity: 0` too to achieve the same result.